# How are font names chosen for LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

I've installed a `ttf` version of Adobe Garamond Pro on my computer (a Mac) using the Font Book application. The font files are in `/Library/Fonts/`. I'm wondering how XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX end up picking the names by which you can refer to the font. The following MWE will compile with XeLaTeX but not LuaLaTeX for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont
  [
    Ligatures={
      TeX,
      Common
    },
    BoldFont={* Semibold}
  ]
  {Adobe Garamond Pro} 

\begin{document}

asdf \textbf{asdf}

\end{document}
```

If I try to compile with LuaLaTeX, I get the following error:

```
Users/adamliter/Library/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/adobe-garamond-pro-italic-2009.luc)
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "AdobeGaramondProSemibold" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.20   {Adobe Garamond Pro}
```

(I believe, however, that there was a point in time—perhaps with TeX Live 2015 or 2016—where I could have compiled that MWE with LuaLaTeX, based on old `.tex` documents that I have on my computer.)

However, the following MWE *does* compile with LuaLaTeX (and also XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont
  [
    Ligatures={
      TeX,
      Common
    },
    BoldFont={AGaramondPro-Semibold}
  ]
  {AGaramondPro-Regular}

\begin{document}

asdf \textbf{asdf}

\end{document}
```

Though it isn't that big of a deal, I do find this is a bit annoying. I'd like to be able to make use of `fontspec`'s ability to specify variants with `*`. But, with LuaLaTeX at least, it seems that I can only refer to the Semibold variant of Adobe Garamond Pro as `AGaramondPro-Semibold`, which precludes me from being able to specify the bold variant as Semibold using `*`.

(Oddly, it seems that I can refer to `AGaramondPro-Regular` as `Adobe Garamond Pro` when using LuaLaTeX. In other words, if I delete the `BoldFont` key-value pair in the first MWE, it compiles with LuaLaTeX just fine.)

Thus, I'm wondering how exactly LuaLaTeX chooses the names by which I can refer to fonts. Is it something about the `.ttf` files? Is there anything I can do to be able to get the first MWE to compile with LuaLaTeX?

Comment: *Hic sunt leones*

Comment: @egreg: I only knew *Hic sunt dracones* in French (if I may say so …).

Comment: @Bernard For some reasons, the former is more used in Italy, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fonts can be found by its symbolic name(s) or file name. By a symbolic name is only possible if the font is saved in a font directory where the system will search for fonts, e.g. `/Library/fonts/`. The symbolic names can be listed with the help of `otfinfo`:

```
voss@shania:~/.fonts/GaramondPro$ otfinfo -i AGaramondPro-Regular.otf 
Family:              Adobe Garamond Pro
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           AGaramondPro-Regular
PostScript name:     AGaramondPro-Regular
[...]
```

or

```
voss@shania:~/.fonts/GaramondPro$ otfinfo -i AGaramondPro-Semibold.otf 
Family:              Adobe Garamond Pro
Subfamily:           Bold
Full name:           AGaramondPro-Semibold
PostScript name:     AGaramondPro-Semibold
Preferred subfamily: Semibold
Mac font menu name:  Adobe Garamond Pro Sb
[...]
```

The following example uses these symbolic names:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{AGaramondPro}[
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Semibold]
\begin{document}

    asdf \textbf{asdf}

\end{document}
```

Using filenames is also possible.

```
\setmainfont{Adobe-Garamond-Pro}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  Path=..., % only for non system font directories needed
  UprightFont = *-Regular_2008,
  BoldFont = *-Bold_2008,
  [...]]
```

If all symbolic fontnames of a family are consistent then a

```
\setmainfont{AGaramondPro}
```

should be enough; `fontspec` will find all other sub families, like regular, bold, italic, a.s.o.

Comment: +1 Ha, thanks! `:)` I should have thought of this. Is there any chance you could say a bit about how these names are determined by LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. I'm also somewhat curious how this works?

Comment: see edited answer ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use (with lualatex) this in your example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont
  [
    Ligatures={
      TeX,
      Common
    },
    UprightFont={*regular},
    BoldFont={*semibold}
  ]
  {agaramondpro}

\begin{document}

asdf \textbf{asdf}

\end{document}
```

But imho the *-versions are not really worth the time invested. Every font family seems to have its own system. It is faster to write the full font name down.

Comment: +1, Thanks. :) Interestingly then, this won't compile with XeLaTeX ... Do you know if there is any possibility that works for both?

Comment: file names normally should work for both.

Comment: LuaTeX (it uses luaotfload) converts all file names to lowercase, but XeTeX (it uses fontconfig) doesn't. So LuaTeX finds the fonts and XeTeX not.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: the file names are `AGaramond-Regular.otf` a.s.o.

Comment: @Herbert: My code above doesn't use file names but fontnames. But it is quite possible that xelatex can't use them.

Comment: @Herbert and UlrikeFischer: the names of the files on my computer are actually things like: `Adobe-Garamond-Pro-Bold_2008.ttf` and `Adobe-Garamond-Pro-Italic_2009.ttf`, *etc.*.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I meant the symbolic font names, not the file names. Look into the `luaotfload-names.lua` file.

Comment: @Herbert the OP stated he is on a Mac. There, XeTeX does not use fontconfig.

Comment: @jfbu: that makes no difference. I suppose OSX uses fontbook for the installation and organisation